# Comparing one string to another string using compareTo method

Tags: string

When comparing string to another string using `compareTO()` method, here we compare one string to another string right. My doubt is which one is argument string in this two

example : `int result = str1.compareTo( str2 );`

Comment: Well, syntactically `str2` is the argument, `str1` is the subject, _if_ that is meant to be an oo notation.For everything else you have to tell us what language that is meant to be.

Comment: in java i have to compare one string to another string..

Comment: If you are referring to a function that takes _two_ arguments and compares them, then yes, that would be procedural style. There are different styles. What is your _real_ question here?

Comment: my question is simple. which is the argument string in these two .     int result = str1.compareTo( str2 );

Comment: Sorry, but that is obvious. And has been answered above. That is a purely syntactical question, and there is only one answer unless you want to argue about artificially setting up a new linguistic concept. I do not understand your first comment in relation to that answer, though.

Comment: ok thaknks for your answer i have one more doubt

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
str1.compareTo(str2)
```

then you get back an integer that is

- negative if `str1` precedes `str2`,
- zero if `str1` equals `str2`, and
- positive if `str1` is comes after `str2`.

Here, `str1` is the receiver object (since it comes before the dot) and `str2` is the argument.